# IOS - cellForRowAtIndexPath skip row

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

Basically, the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function need to return a UITableViewCell. In my code, I would like to check a behaviour that will check something and skip the cell if a specific value is found.

Here's what I have right now :

```
static NSString *FirstCellIdentifier = @"First Custom Cell";
static NSString *SecondCellIdentifier = @"Second Custom Cell";

CustomObject *o = [_customObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

if ([s.name isEqualToString:@""])
{
    FirstCellController *cell = [customList dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:FirstCellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) { 
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FirstCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects){
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]){
                cell = (FirstCellController *) currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    // Here I do something with the cell's content
    return cell;
}
else {
    SecondCellController *cell = [customList dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SecondCellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SecondCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects){
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]){
                cell = (SecondCellController *) currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    // Here i do something with the cell's content
    return cell;
}
```

What I'd like to do is that if the `s.name` is not empty, I would like to "skip" the cell, not displaying it and go to the next one.

Anyone have some advice on this please ?

Thanks.

Comment: And how is your code working so far ? What do you see ?

Comment: And have you tried returning *nil* when you want to skip the cell ? It may create some troubles but you should try anyways. Or maybe work on *heightForRowAtIndexPath:* and set height for 0 when you don't want the cell to show ?

Comment: @rdurand, returning nil will result in app crash. I would go with setting cell height to 0 as well

Comment: @rdurand indeed, I tried to return nil before asking here, but as Vladimir is saying, this results in an app crash.

Comment: you cannot return nil from cellForRowAtIndexPath. Per Apple docs "An assertion is raised if you return nil."

Comment: for me it was that I forgot to add `numberOfRowsInSection`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You cannot "skip" a cell this way.  If your datasource claims there are `n` rows, then you have to provide a cell for each of them.  The correct way would be to modify your datasource to claim `(n-1)` rows when you want to remove one, then call UITableView `reloadData` to have it regenerate the table (and ask you for new cells for each visible row).

Another option would be to "hide" a row/cell.  The technique I've used for this is to provide a height of 0 for the given cell via `heightForRowAtIndexPath`:

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried modifying my `heightForRowAtIndexPath` function, and I don't have the behaviour I was looking for. Indeed, the row's height is correctly set to 0, but the content is still showing.

Comment: Ok I managed to do what I want by creating a new "empty" tableviewcell with a height of 0, and load this nib instead of my previous one.

Comment: If the content is still showing then the cell is not clipping to it's frame.  In cellForRowAtIndexPath: when you create the cell, set cell.clipsToBounds = YES;

Comment: When you change the height to 0, won't you still see the separator for that cell?

Answer (score 1):

Like tom said, don't try to "skip" in the UITableViewDelegate methods but instead put this logic in the UITableViewDataSource methods ... As an example, you can set up a common method to filter out your data:

```
- (NSArray*)tableData {
    NSMutableArray *displayableObjects = [NSMutableArray array];
    [displayableObjects enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        CustomObject *customObject = (YourCustomObject *)obj;
        if (customObject.name && ![customObject.name isEqualToString:@""]) {
            // only show in the table if name is populated
            [displayableObjects addObject:customObject];
        }
    }];
    return displayableObjects;
}
```

and then in your datasource methods, use that to get the pre-filtered data that you want displayed in the table:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [[self tableData] count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CustomObject *o = [[self tableData] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    ....
}
```

This way whenever reloadData is called it will always skip the filtered data when building the cells.

Answer (score -1):

You can Skip a cell by not showing it in the table view. (I Assume thats what u want)
Just use this:

```
cell.hidden = YES;
return cell
```

EDIT: Not a valid Solution. (Leaves Blank space in place of the cell)

Comment: Won't this solution juste "hide" the cell, leaving a blank space in the list ?

Comment: i did not think of that. Need to test it! Confirm if you can! Thankx

Comment: @Yellow Just Tested this solution. You're Right. This is not a valid solution.